# dotnet core - Entity Framework - problems with creation of migration - cant find SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the latest Visual Studio 2019 preview 3.1.200-preview-014883.

I am trying to run the creation of a migration using this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add INITIAL --context CATALOGContext -s ../Jobsledger.API
```

but am getting the message:

```
Install the [3.1.200] .NET Core SDK or update [C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0 - AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.CATALOG\global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.200-preview-014883 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I've upgraded Visual Studio - and updated global.json with the following:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "3.1.200"
    }
}
```

How do I run the migration - what am I missing here as I thought I had the SDK installed with the preview?

UPDATE: I ran the following

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

and got the following:

```
Install the [3.1.200] .NET Core SDK or update [C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0 - AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.CATALOG\global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  3.1.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.200-preview-014883 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
PS C:\Users\simon\OneDrive\Documents\1.0 - AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.1\JobsLedger.CATALOG>
```

I also ran

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.2
```

and got the same as above..

Comment: if you run `dotnet --version`?What do you see?

Comment: I ran dotnet --version and got 3.1.200-preview-014883,, So it does exist. Will now unistall VS in its entirety and do a complete install.

Comment: I am not sure what is happening? I can only guess...Sorry. The next steps i would check if the `Design Package of EF`, which is responsible for migrations if is installed in my project. I would also test with visual studio's package manager console ->https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Will see how the install goes... thankyou for having a look.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this has any merit but the first thing I did was remove Visual Studio 2019 preview. Rebooted... and then rerun the migration.

While investigating I read an article by [Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Aug/21/Visual-Studio-20192-and-NET-30-SDK-Projects-not-Loading) That had a similar issue. He did say use global.json which I had done however I updated the file to reflect the exact build of the SDK.

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "3.1.200-preview-014883"
    }
}
```

Clean install and the correct version in the global.json file and it finally worked.  Rick did say this was a terrible idea because you are tied to that version of the sdk. He did outline other options but I did look into the Visual Studio options however VS2019 had been changed.. it works right now.. I'll make it bomb proof later.